# Expand the full path of a file! in Rebol without get-modes

Tags: path, filenames, rebol

In Rebol 2, it is possible to get the full path of a file by using `get-modes`, e.g.

```
>> get-modes %foo.r 'full-path
== %/home/hostilefork/foo.r
```

The function `get-modes` is not in Rebol 3.  How do you get the equivalent behavior?

*Note that `` `full-path `` [doesn't even seem to be mentioned](http://www.rebol.com/docs/words/wget-modes.html) as a known parameter in the Rebol 2 documentation.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new function [`clean-path`](http://www.rebol.com/r3/docs/functions/clean-path.html) does that *specific* thing:

```
>> clean-path %foo.r
== %/home/hostilefork/foo.r
```

As for the rest of the functionality offered by `get-modes`, the port model in Rebol 3 seems to be still in flux (or at least has little documentation, besides [a wiki page of examples](http://www.rebol.net/wiki/Port_Examples)).  In describing the motivations behind changes to Rebol 3, Carl Sassenrath cited [Rebol 2 ports as flawed](http://www.rebol.com/rebol3/motivation.html):

> I believe that some of the main design principles of REBOL ports were flawed. Second-order features (such as port field auto-inheritance or even the port-as-a-series concept) were placed above first-order features (like easy I/O access methods) and too many variations of external devices were squeezed into a single port definition, resulting in a large bloated port object.

So if any other `get-modes` functionality is needed, it will probably require some hunting and experimentation for the moment.